# Python collapsible sidebar on tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am creating a multi tool in python that has a collapsible sidebar for navigation however i am pretty new to tkinter and python itself that itself is the reason I am asking this question. I have no code because this is the first thing I thought of working on and all the tutorials there are on Javascript or some over programming language.

Comment: Cool, do you have a question?

Comment: You haven't asked a question. A question like "how to create a collapsible sidebar" are too broad and vague. You need to work through a tkinter tutorial to understand the basics, and then attempt to create it yourself before coming here with a more specific question.

Comment: Pick one from [`[python][tkinter] sidebar`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=is%3aquestion%20%5bpython%5d%5btkinter%5d%20sidebar)

Comment: What do you mean all the tutorials are on "javascript or some other programming language." I am 100% sure there is a vast number of python and tkinter tutorials out there. I have made a collapsible frame myself for one of my applications and it is a simple matter of writing a function that can toggle the geometry manager on and off.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple example of how to create a collapsible frame. You can use the same method to create a collapsible sidebar by putting all your sidebar stuff in the frame.

```
import tkinter as tk


class Example(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.geometry('300x100')
        self.left_frame = tk.Frame(self)
        self.left_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')
        self.right_frame = tk.Frame(self)
        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        for i in range(3):
            self.columnconfigure(i, weight=1)

        tk.Label(self.left_frame, text='Left Frame').grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')
        tk.Label(self.right_frame, text='Right Frame').grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')

        self.frame_status = False
        self.ar_btn = tk.Button(self, text="▶", width=1, command=self.toggle_right_frame)
        self.ar_btn.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky='nse')

    def toggle_right_frame(self):
        if self.frame_status:
            self.right_frame.grid_forget()
            self.frame_status = False
            self.ar_btn.config(text="▶")
        else:
            self.frame_status = True
            self.right_frame.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='nsew')
            self.ar_btn.config(text="◀")

Example().mainloop()
```

Results:

[image]

[image]